# in entity framework code first, how to use KeyAttribute on multiple columns

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-4.1, code-first

I'm creating a POCO model to use with entity framework code first CTP5.  I'm using the <key()> decoration to make a property map to a PK column.  But how can I define a PK on more then one column, and specifically, how can I control order of the columns in the index?  Is it a result of the order of properties in the class?

Edit: look at @kara's answer for an updated solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 169, accepted):

**NOTE:**
As of 2019 this answer became non-valid for later EntityFramework versions.

You can specify the column order in the attributes, for instance:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    [Key, Column(Order=0)]
    public int MyFirstKeyProperty { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=1)]
    public int MySecondKeyProperty { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order=2)]
    public string MyThirdKeyProperty { get; set; }

    // other properties
}
```

If you are using the `Find` method of a `DbSet` you must take this order for the key parameters into account.

Comment: InvalidOperationException: Entity type 'XXX' has composite primary key defined with data annotations. To set composite primary key, use fluent API.

Answer (score 73):

To complete the correct answer submitted by Slauma, you can use the *HasKey* method to specify an order for composite primary keys as well:

```
public class User
{        
    public int UserId { get; set; }       
    public string Username { get; set; }        
}        

public class Ctp5Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => new 
        { 
            u.UserId, 
            u.Username 
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - both methods do work fine.  I prefer the Attributes because I'm generating my classes from code, and attributes are much more concise.

Comment: I personally also add the Propety(x...).HasColumnOrder(0...n) to each of the keyed properties.  Is that good, bad, indifferent?

Comment: This answer will work for latest EF-versions.

Answer (score 12):

If, like me, you prefer to use a configuration file you can do that in this way (based on Manavi's example):

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}  

public class UserConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Users");
        HasKey(x => new {x.UserId, x.Username});
    }
}
```

Obviously you have to add the configuration file to your context:

```
public class Ctp5Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new UserConfiguration());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

In **EF Core 7.0** a new attribute for classes `[PrimaryKey]` was introduced.

Example:

```
[PrimaryKey(nameof(FirstName),nameof(LastName))]
public class Person
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

This way, you don't have to use the fluent-api again.

Comment: Thank you @kara. This question was asked in 2011, referring to ef5 and was consistently popular. It documents the change through ef6 and now efc7, and should be turned into a wiki entry...

Answer (score 0):

Use as a anonymous object:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserExamAttemptQuestion>().ToTable("Users").HasKey(o => new { o.UserId, o.Username });
```