# in entity framework code first, why is the key not unique

Tags: entity-framework

I have used the methods specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4950245/in-entity-framework-code-first-how-to-use-keyattribute-on-multiple-columns) to create composite keys.  SQL Server calls it a PrimaryKey, but it is not unique (!).  Is there a way to specify uniqueness in attributes or fluent API?  I've found several hacks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4413084/unique-constraint-in-entity-framework-code-first) but this should be possible to do upfront...

The non unique value combinations are a result of an SQLBulkCopy operation.  Is it possible this is the reason?

[edit] my assumptions were wrong - read on to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mistake! The keys are unique, including composite keys.  My problem was in the column mapping of the SqlBulCopy class.  I was doing

```
Public Sub DoBulKCopy(dt As DataTable, cns As String)
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cns)
    cn.Open()
    Dim copy As New SqlBulkCopy(cn)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(i,i)
    Next
```

While I should have been doing

```
Public Sub DoBulKCopy(dt As DataTable, cns As String)
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(cns)
    cn.Open()
    Dim copy As New SqlBulkCopy(cn)
    For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
        copy.ColumnMappings.Add(dt.Columns(i).ColumnName, dt.Columns(i).ColumnName)
    Next
```

And not assuming the column order is the same.

HTH

Answer (score 1):

The uniqueness in a composite key is the combined values of all the keys. You can have repeated values in any single column, but all the key columns as a whole cannot be repeated as a sequence.

Comment: I am aware of that.  But after an SQLBulkLoad operation, I am able to get combined values which are not unique.  Now that I think about it, this may be the result of the SQLBulkLoad itself... I'll edit.