# How do I deal with a lack of a primary key in Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

With Entity Framework, whenever I "update model from database" inside Visual Studio the model that's created isn't usable.

The issue is that EF doesn't handle tables without a primary key very well.  It treats them as a view, which in turn prevents you from editing the table with EF.  You can override this behavior by opening the model (edmx file) as an XML file and making a few changes to the EntitySet definition.  It's annoying to do this over and over.  Has anyone found a more permanent workaround besides adding a primary key or modifying the edmx file after every update?

By the way, I am using a unique key but it's spread across two columns.  It'd be nice if EF could handle this, but as of EF 4.2 it doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand - you're using a "unique key" (I assume you mean a unique index or a unique constraint) because the key has two columns? You can create a primary key with multiple columns. I'm not sure why EF would treat a two-column key differently than a single-column primary key, but here is a simple example of a multiple-column primary key:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.foobar
(
    fooID INT,
    barID INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (fooID, barID)
);
```

Of course there is other syntax that allows you to create the constraint after the fact, and you should also name your constraint explicitly, but just wanted to show a simple example.

Comment: Ah ha.  What I had before was a unique nonclustered key.  I dropped that and added a two column primary key as you described.  EF imports this just fine, and this solves the problem.  By the way, I just found that you can add a multi-column primary key by selecting each column in SQL Management Studio, and click "Add Primary Key".  Pretty neat, and funny I hadn't discovered that before.

Answer (score 3):

> By the way, I am using a unique key but it's spread across two columns. It'd be nice if EF could handle this, but as of EF 4.2 it doesn't.

[Yes it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4950571/98713) ;)

Comment: Is this something that would work better with a Code First approach?  The reason I ask is that the scenario I described above (Database First) is with a two-column unique key defined in SQL which isn't porting over to EF automatically.

Comment: I had the same issue. I had to go in and add a single primary key column, and make the two original columns a unique index. Then and only then would EF import the table correctly.