# Map multiple PK with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, fluent

I have 2 classes at the moment. The first is an asset, the second is services associated with that asset. The Asset table in SQL Server has a PK over both ID and workflow_id.

```
public class Asset
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int workflow_id { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

The second table is services which has a PK over the 3 columns, the service ID, workflow_id and the asset_id the service is tied too.

```
public class Services
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int workflow_id { get; set; }
    public int asset_id { get; set; }

    public string service_description { get; set; }
}
```

Example Data: Asset with ID#10 in workflow_id#27 matches all the Services with asset_id#10 in workflow_id#27.

How can I map these two together with the multi-column PKs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the columns that you want to be PK's. In your example for the first model you would have:

```
    [Key, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(Order = 0)]
    public int ID { get; set; }


    [Key, System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema.Column(Order = 1)]
    public int workflow_id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do those annotations with the multiple columns using the Fluent API?

Comment: I found a solution to that by @MortezaManavi [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4950635/1594318)